# Need more information on xml object returned from ajax jquery call

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I'm using Jquery to make a call to the Weather Underground XML api. Below the function I have defined when document is ready in the browser. Pretty simple stuff. One thing I'm curious about is the xml object returned when I use the dataType set to "xml". I see a lot of examples where people call functions like returned_xml.find( ) to locate specific elements in the xml. I can't seem to locate very good documentation on the api of the xml object. Any pointers ? Thx

```
$(document).ready(function () {
          jQuery.support.cors = true; // force cross-site scripting (as of jQuery 1.5)
        $.ajax(
                   {     url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/0787878787878/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.xml", 
                    dataType : "xml", 
                    success : function(returned_xml) 
                    { alert("Data is " + returned_xml.xml ); 
                        },
                    error  : function(failed_data)
                    {
                        alert("failed with " + failed_data);
                    } 
                   }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this API from jquery [jQuery.parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)